# Why would my cooktop burner short across the bottom of a pot?

Tags: appliances

I had a stainless steel (?) saucepan cooking on my electric stove and there was a buzz and shower of sparks and the element went out. The bottom of the pan has a black mark, kind of like what happens to a screwdriver if you put it against two house terminals. The heating element on the stove has two pits on it now, apparently where the arc went. The element is in the shape of a spiral and it apparently arced from one arm of the spiral to the adjoining one. I have shown with a red line on the picture below approximately where the arc went:

[image]

I suppose a steel saucepan is electrically conductive, so it can conduct electricity. The question is why does it not happen every time? Is there insulating surface on the element (which has worn away maybe)? Does the element just get more and more resistive as it ages until a pan conducts better?

Another strange thing is that the lamp of the burner went out after the arc, but after I turned the burner off and on, it came on again and seemed to be heating normally.

Comment: I believe that copper pans would be a problem for all such heating elements if the heating elements weren't themselves coated to avoid the problem. Chances are that you already had a worn/damaged heating element that had removed some of this protective coating and exposed the inner nichrome to direct contact with the pan. So yes, your pan did short it out. But you just need to replace the burner element and you should be okay.

Comment: The spiral is iron - and conductive - and should be grounded to the house safety ground. It is a tube, filled with ceramic material to insulate it from a heating wire (inside, connected to those spade clips or wire ends). Resistance measurements should confirm all this on a good element. Normal failure mode should result in AC voltage conducted to ground via the spiral, and fuse/breaker disconnection from supply. If that didn't happen, I'd check the installation carefully, wrt earthing and breakers. The pan was merely an agent, bending the damaged element until the short occurred.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the failed element? In particular, a close-up of the failure spot. Without it, I think this question can only be answered by speculation...

Answer (score 1):

As Brian commented, the heating  element is not supposed to be under any voltage. The metal tube must be isolated from actual heating wire. If you have these sparks flying under conductive pans, you have a broken heating element on your stove. Please **stop using it immediately**, it is a serious life-threatening hazard, and refer the stove to qualified repair service.

Comment: This nanny answer does not address the question. The question is seeking an answer to how the element works and possible reasons for the short described.

Comment: @TylerDurden, childish questions deserve nanny answers. You've been told that the actual heater wire should be isolated from the metal jacket. Loading the element with a heavy pot causes deformation of the jacket, so the internal short might be intermittent. It sounds like your element was defective from the beginning. Simple experiments with a multi-meter and pushing-deforming the element should clear the question.